# Interval Date to days

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select
CREATION_DATE,
APPROVED_DATE,
REQUISITION_NUMBER,

from POR_REQUISITION_HEADERS_ALL 

where
CREATION_DATE >= '2021-4-11' 
and APPROVED_DATE Is NOT null
```

Is there any way to subtract `APPROVED_DATE - CREATION_DATE` and get the difference of days and mins and seconds into days?

The error I got when I try

> inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND

- CREATION_DATE   2021-04-13T21:27:56.089+00:00
- APPROVED_DATE   2021-04-20T08:18:04.222+00:00

The output I want would be `6.9 days` for example

There is any help thanks anyway.

Comment: What is the data type of `creation_date` and `approved_date`?  The names imply that they are dates.  The error indicates that they are likely some form of timestamp but I'm not sure what code threw the error you posted.  Or you could be storing the data in a `varchar2` column

Comment: the line i got for this error are  AVG(pola.dayss) xx , pola.APPROVED_DATE- add_months(pola.CREATION_DATE,trunc( months_between(pola.CREATION_DATE,pola.APPROVED_DATE ) )) dayss
 when I try to run it I got this error inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND

Comment: OK.  It's really helpful to edit this into the text of your question.   Specifying an error without including the code that is causing the error is confusing.  Back to my original question, though, what is the data type of the `creation_date` and `approved_date` columns?  Again, I'm guessing from the error that they are some form of timestamp despite the name implying that they are dates.

Comment: I don`t know what is the data type but it is date and the output are 2021-04-13T21:27:56.089+00:00

Comment: Sorry, why don't you know what the data type of the column is?  Can't you look at the table definition?  `date`, `timestamp`, `timestamp with time zone`, `timestamp with local time zone` and `varchar2` are all different data types and you'd need to handle them differently.

Comment: You can find out the datatype by doing a ```DESCRIBE POR_REQUISITION_HEADERS_ALL```or by checking the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/procurement/20d/oedmp/self-service-procurement.html#poramxapprovalgroups-22458 This will tell you that the datatype of those 2 columns is ```TIMESTAMP```